# Flutter local notification schedule - not working as expected

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to show notification daily on a specified time and I have implemented the code to show daily notification but it is not working not showing a notification at the time I want to call. I am using this plugin [link](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications)

When I run The App I got this warning on Console here is the screenshot
[image: a busy cat]

Is my implementation of the code wrong?
Here is the code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'dart:async';

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AppState createState() => _AppState();
}


class _AppState extends State<App> {
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = new FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  showNotification() async{
    var time = new Time(3,51, 0);//at 3.30 
    var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
    new AndroidNotificationDetails('repeatDailyAtTime channel id',
        'repeatDailyAtTime channel name', 'repeatDailyAtTime description');
    var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics =
    new IOSNotificationDetails();
    var platformChannelSpecifics = new NotificationDetails(
    androidPlatformChannelSpecifics, iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.showDailyAtTime(
        0,
        'Teer Result Time',
        'Open The App and check for the Result',
        time,
        platformChannelSpecifics);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    showNotification();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(

    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to first initialize Local Notification plugin.

Just add the initialization code to your initstate, as shown below:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
    import 'dart:async';

    class App extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _AppState createState() => _AppState();
    }


    class _AppState extends State<App> {
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = new FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

      showNotification() async{
        var time = new Time(3,51, 0);//at 3.30 
        var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
        new AndroidNotificationDetails('repeatDailyAtTime channel id',
            'repeatDailyAtTime channel name', 'repeatDailyAtTime description');
        var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics =
        new IOSNotificationDetails();
        var platformChannelSpecifics = new NotificationDetails(
        androidPlatformChannelSpecifics, iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);
        await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.showDailyAtTime(
            0,
            'Teer Result Time',
            'Open The App and check for the Result',
            time,
            platformChannelSpecifics);
      }

      @override
      void initState() {
        // TODO: implement initState
        super.initState();
        //-------------------- Initialization Code---------------------
        FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    // initialise the plugin. app_icon needs to be a added as a drawable resource to the Android head project
    var initializationSettingsAndroid = AndroidInitializationSettings('app_icon');
    var initializationSettingsIOS = IOSInitializationSettings(
        onDidReceiveLocalNotification: onDidReceiveLocalNotification);
    var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
        initializationSettingsAndroid, initializationSettingsIOS);
   //--------------------------------------
        showNotification();
      }
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(

        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem, I found that I didn't add some required permissions and receivers in my manifest, all the details are written in the docs under the Scheduled notifications title, as well as this [link](https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications/blob/master/flutter_local_notifications/example/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml) to the example project manifest as a reference.

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard of one report where this issue happened as their app hadn't been migrated to AndroidX, although the error wouldn't imply that. Have you looked at that yet? See https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility#how-to-migrate-a-flutter-app-to-androidx